# Cuda error with render layers

Tags: render-layers

I have a scene that rendered perfectly with my GPU, in 960x540. As I had a Cuda error when trying to render this scene in 1920x1080, I decided to use Render Layers. Now, I have a Cuda error every time I try to render it, even in 960x540... And when I erase all the Render Layers, it renders just fine.

I don't really understand why using Render Layers does this, as it should do the opposite :/

**Edit :**

The error is "Cuda error: Out of memory in cuMemAlloc(&device_pointer, size)". I'm using Blender 2.79, my graphic card is a GTX 960 with 4GB of VRAM. I'm using Linux Mint 18.2.
The scene uses 112Mb of memory: it's a pretty simple scene with less than 20 objects and one lamp, a particle system, two 3K textures and Adaptive Subsurf on some objects. There are 74,873 tris.

**Edit 2 :**

This is not the same problem as here : [CUDA error: Out of memory in cuMemAlloc(&device_pointer, size)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/cuda-error-out-of-memory-in-cumemallocdevice-pointer-size). My problem is related to Render Layers, as said before.

---

*Sorry for the engrish :X*

Comment: Are you waiting for an answer? Without even actually TELLING US the error message? Also, which GPU, how much VRAM, memory usage of the scene, etc, etc.

Comment: @Reaper I updated the post

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/cuda-error-out-of-memory-in-cumemallocdevice-pointer-size

Comment: @Reaper, no it's not the same thing. My problem is related to Render Layers, as said in the post.

Answer (score 1):

When using Render Layers don't forget exclude layers, if they invisible.

[image]

If you doesn't exclude layer, it will be loaded into memory even if turned off. Objects on invisible layers will be visible in reflections, shadows, and can be mask (`Mask Layer` option). So, if you really want to layer don't load into memory, mark them as `Exclude`.